# Android - ListView in Fragment does not showing up

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-arrayadapter

Here is my code that is having problems. I am trying to update my sqlite database data in `ListView` after entering an event, but the `ListView` is not showing, and I am bad in using fragment, can anyone guide me to what I am doing wrong here? Sorry I am new to android apps development. Thank you.

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.event, container, false);
    show = (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.button1);
    show.setOnClickListener(this);
    return rootView;
}

public void onActivityCreated(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> eventList = controller
            .getAllEvents();
    if (eventList.size() != 0) {
        ListView lv = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.list);
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                eventId = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.eventId);
                String valEventId = eventId.getText().toString();
                Intent objIndent = new Intent(getActivity(),
                        EditEvent.class);
                objIndent.putExtra("eventId", valEventId);
                startActivity(objIndent);
            }
        });
        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(), eventList,
                R.layout.view_event_entry, new String[] { "eventId",
                        "eventName" }, new int[] { R.id.eventId,
                        R.id.eventName });
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Intent objIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), AddEvent.class);
    startActivity(objIntent);
}
```

Here is my xml code:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/addevents"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@id/relativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout1"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp">

<ListView
     android:id="@+id/list"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignParentLeft="true">
 </ListView>
 </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is the code for setting up my database. I wonder if this is where the problem happens. You guys can check it out here.

```
public EventController(Context applicationcontext) {
    super(applicationcontext, "androidsqlite.db", null, 1);
    Log.d(LOGCAT,"Created");
}

@Override
//create table for the database
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {
    String query;
    query = "CREATE TABLE events ( eventId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, eventName TEXT)";
    database.execSQL(query);    
    Log.d(LOGCAT,"events Created");
}

@Override
//drop the database and reset if required
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase database, int version_old, int current_version) {
    String query;
    query = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS events";
    database.execSQL(query);
    onCreate(database);
}

public void insertEvent(HashMap<String, String> queryValues) {
    SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put("eventName", queryValues.get("eventName"));
    database.insert("events", null, values);
    database.close();
}

public int updateEvent(HashMap<String, String> queryValues) {
    SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();    
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put("eventName", queryValues.get("eventName"));
    return database.update("events", values, "eventId" + " = ?", new String[] { queryValues.get("eventId") });
    //String updateQuery = "Update  words set txtWord='"+word+"' where txtWord='"+ oldWord +"'";
    //Log.d(LOGCAT,updateQuery);
    //database.rawQuery(updateQuery, null);
    //return database.update("words", values, "txtWord  = ?", new String[] { word });
}

public void deleteEvent(String id) {
    Log.d(LOGCAT,"delete");
    SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();    
    String deleteQuery = "DELETE FROM  events where eventId='"+ id +"'";
    Log.d("query",deleteQuery);     
    database.execSQL(deleteQuery);
}

public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> getAllEvents() {
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> wordList;
    wordList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM events";
    SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            map.put("eventId", cursor.getString(0));
            map.put("eventName", cursor.getString(1));
            wordList.add(map);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    // return contact list
    return wordList;
}

public HashMap<String, String> getEventInfo(String id) {
    HashMap<String, String> wordList = new HashMap<String, String>();
    SQLiteDatabase database = this.getReadableDatabase();
    String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM events where eventId='"+id+"'";
    Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
                //HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            wordList.put("eventName", cursor.getString(1));
               //wordList.add(map);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }                   
return wordList;
}
```

Here is the error I got:

> 10-26 08:02:29.141: E/AndroidRuntime(22646): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   10-26 08:02:29.141: E/AndroidRuntime(22646): java.lang.NullPointerException
>   10-26 08:02:29.141: E/AndroidRuntime(22646):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:224)
>   10-26 08:02:29.141: E/AndroidRuntime(22646):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:164)
>   10-26 08:02:29.141: E/AndroidRuntime(22646):    at com.example.hapshare.EventController.getAllEvents(EventController.java:70)
>   10-26 08:02:29.141: E/AndroidRuntime(22646):    at com.example.hapshare.Event.onCreateView(Event.java:42)
>   10-26 08:02:29.141: E/AndroidRuntime(22646):    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1478)
>   10-26 08:02:29.141: E/AndroidRuntime(22646):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:927)
>   10-26 08:02:29.141: E/AndroidRuntime(22646):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
>   10-26 08:02:29.141: E/AndroidRuntime(22646):    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
>   10-26 08:02:29.141: E/AndroidRuntime(22646):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1460)
>   10-26 08:02:29.141: E/AndroidRuntime(22646):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:472)
>   10-26 08:02:29.141: E/AndroidRuntime(22646):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:141)
>   10-26 08:02:29.141: E/AndroidRuntime(22646):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1068)
>   10-26 08:02:29.141: E/AndroidRuntime(22646):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:914)
>   10-26 08:02:29.141: E/AndroidRuntime(22646):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1436)
>   10-26 08:02:29.141: E/AndroidRuntime(22646):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15696)
>   10-26 08:02:29.141: E/AndroidRuntime(22646):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4851)
>   10-26 08:02:29.141: E/AndroidRuntime(22646):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
>   10-26 08:02:29.141: E/AndroidRuntime(22646):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15696)
>   10-26 08:02:29.141: E/AndroidRuntime(22646):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:847)
>   10-26 08:02:29.141: E/AndroidRuntime(22646):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
>   10-26 08:02:29.141: E/AndroidRuntime(22646):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15696)
>   10-26 08:02:29.141: E/AndroidRuntime(22646):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4851)
>   10-26 08:02:29.141: E/AndroidRuntime(22646):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
>   10-26 08:02:29.141: E/AndroidRuntime(22646):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2261)
>   10-26 08:02:29.141: E/AndroidRuntime(22646):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15696)
>   10-26 08:02:29.141: E/AndroidRuntime(22646):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2221)
>   10-26 08:02:29.141: E/AndroidRuntime(22646):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1287)
>   10-26 08:02:29.141: E/AndroidRuntime(22646):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1524)
>   10-26 08:02:29.141: E/AndroidRuntime(22646):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1187)
>   10-26 08:02:29.141: E/AndroidRuntime(22646):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4855)
>   10-26 08:02:29.141: E/AndroidRuntime(22646):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:766)
>   10-26 08:02:29.141: E/AndroidRuntime(22646):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:575)
>   10-26 08:02:29.141: E/AndroidRuntime(22646):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:542)
>   10-26 08:02:29.141: E/AndroidRuntime(22646):    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:751)
>   10-26 08:02:29.141: E/AndroidRuntime(22646):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
>   10-26 08:02:29.141: E/AndroidRuntime(22646):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
>   10-26 08:02:29.141: E/AndroidRuntime(22646):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
>   10-26 08:02:29.141: E/AndroidRuntime(22646):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5777)
>   10-26 08:02:29.141: E/AndroidRuntime(22646):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   10-26 08:02:29.141: E/AndroidRuntime(22646):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>   10-26 08:02:29.141: E/AndroidRuntime(22646):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1083)
>   10-26 08:02:29.141: E/AndroidRuntime(22646):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:850)
>   10-26 08:02:29.141: E/AndroidRuntime(22646):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: `rootView` is not a class ember but you are using the same to initialize listview

Comment: Building off of the above comment, if you're not getting an error, it also means that there's no data to put in your list, meaning it would be empty regardless.

Comment: Hey. You might want to check an accepted answer if one of them solved your problem.

Answer (score 3):

There are a few things that raise red flags in your code. Which leads me to my first question: are you using eclipse or intellij? Because it doesn't look like it'll even compile to me. Maybe you edited this on here, but now to help you get it working. Don't even use `onActivityCreated` for initializing your `ListView` in a Fragment (Andrew also correctly brought up the point that you aren't even using it correctly, which is why I am surprised its even compiling if it is). You should be doing it in `onCreateView`. Now I will post your code that I have edited. I am not testing it so it serves as a better guide to what it should look like (and hopefully it compiles).

```
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.event, container, false);

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> eventList = controller
            .getAllEvents();
    if (eventList.size() != 0) {
        ListView lv = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.list);
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                eventId = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.eventId);
                String valEventId = eventId.getText().toString();
                Intent objIndent = new Intent(getActivity(),
                        EditEvent.class);
                objIndent.putExtra("eventId", valEventId);
                startActivity(objIndent);
            }
        });
        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(), eventList,
                R.layout.view_event_entry, new String[] { "eventId",
                        "eventName" }, new int[] { R.id.eventId,
                        R.id.eventName });
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
    show = (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.button1);
    show.setOnClickListener(this);

    return rootView;
}
...
```

Comment: This explanation is better and ought to fix his problem.

On a side note, the reason it compiles with his wrong header is because Java just treats it like an overloaded method, but seeing as it doesn't follow what Android expects, it just never runs.

Comment: Thanks @AndrewSchuster And good point. I am just surprised that `rootView` was not causing an error since its doesn't look global in the `onActivityCreated` context. At least I fail to see it. Either way thanks for pointing out the overloaded method.

Comment: Hi @Andy i tried your code but still getting error. This time i'm getting a null pointer exception error. I wonder is it i declare the listview wrongly? (I am using Eclipse)

Comment: hi @AndrewSchuster , once i use the correct format which is (public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceStates) ) , the application crash,i think there is some other problem in my code caused the listview never called.

Comment: i think the code that caused error is the listview until setAdapter, because once i delete the code the application works fine, but i still can't find any error in that.

Comment: Umm, the code I provided should work conceptually lol (humans aren't compilers unfortunately). I figured there would be something. Its best if you post the logcat error in its entirety so I can see it. It would be even more helpful if I knew where that null pointer was coming from.

Comment: @Andy i updated my question with logcat, as u see there is a null pointer exception on second row.

Comment: Well it seems the null pointer is coming from trying to access something in the cursor that isn't there. I assume whatever that in the 0 index of the cursor is id or _id right? Like I said, I am not a compiler so I would have to run and debug to know what exactly causes the problem. But what I do know is your issue is definitely from `getEventInfo` in your SQLite helper. And my guess is theres either nothing in the database, or your inputting data wrong in the database. So basically debug that.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few things wrong with this.  First off, you overrode `onActivityCreated()` incorrectly.  Instead of what you have, it should have the following header:

```
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceStates)
```

Because you use the wrong header, it is never called.

Secondly, you may get some errors from using `rootView` in your `onActivityCreated()` method because it is not declared in that method.  Consider calling `getView()` instead, as that returns the rootView for you.